# How to redirect to lead convert page in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a scenario where some custom logic needs to be executed and ask confirmation before redirect to the standard lead convert page using custom lightning action. I tried to use below approch:

```
var leadId = component.get("v.recordId");
var convertUrl = '/lead/leadconvert.jsp?retURL=%2F' +leadId + '&id=' + leadId;
var eUrl = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
eUrl.setParams({
    "url": convertUrl
     });
eUrl.fire();
```

but it is not automatically redirecting to the page and also it opens in new tab. later found that it is happening because of the classic URL. May I know how to do this in lightning?